# Prove if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c a_n$ is convergent then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c a_n=c \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$, where $c \in \mathbb C$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c a_n$ is convergent then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c a_n=c \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$, where $c \in \mathbb C$.

I've a theorem saying that if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent, then so is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ca_n$ with limit $c\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$

But I want to go "the other way", that is show $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is also convergent and the limit of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c a_n$ is $ c \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$.

Does this theorem silently prove the other way by implying that I should multiply by $c^{-1}$ to obtain $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c^{-1} c a_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = c^{-1} c \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ ? If yes, why is the theorem not proving both ways ?

Comment: The method you suggest is perfectly fine for non zero $c$. But I didn't get your last sentence.

Comment: So what I want to prove follows as an corollary from the theorem I know?

Answer (score 2):

Do you know that for $(b_n)$ a convergent sequence and for a complex $\lambda$ we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda b_n=\lambda\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n\qquad?$$
If yes then take
$$b_n=\sum_{k=0}^na_n$$